# DevExpress. Как добавить SplashScreenManager в ToolBox? "Repair Toolbox" не помог

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, devexpress

Хочу добавить на форму SplashScreenManager, только его нет в ToolBox. Пробовал сделать RepairToolbox, обновил DevExpress - не помогает.

В окне добавления элементов он галочкой отмечен, но на панели элементов его нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Как добавить SplashScreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, что версия .NET Framework в настройках проекта 4.5.2 и выше, т.к. DevExpress перешли на эту версию начиная с 18.2 ( https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/8092/Prerequisites ) Если вы используете версию DevExpress компонент старее 18.2, убедитесь, что она поддерживает Visual Studio 2017 (смотрите нижнюю табличку в документе)